# Large vectors and memory conservation c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, large-data

I'm working on making a tile-map editor in C++. Right now, while a map is being edited, its attributes are stored across three vectors:

```
vector<vector<vector<bool>>> CanvasCollisionObstruction; //[collision,obstruction][map x][map y]
vector<vector<vector<bool>>> CanvasZoneOverlays; //zone overlays for programmable map zones [zone type][map x][map y]
vector<vector<vector<canvasClip>>> CanvasClips; //identifies which sprite occupies this tile [layer number][map x][map y]
```

In the above vectors, the 2nd and 3rd dimensions ([map x] and [map y]) refer to the actual tile coordinates on the map. These are just plain-old-square-2d maps. The type of that last vector is the following struct:

```
struct canvasClip
{
    int tileset;
    int clip;
    //initialization to check if it's in-use
    canvasClip() : tileset(-1), clip(-1) {}
    bool isInitialized()
    {//a clip is only rendered if it is initialized
        return ((tileset >= 0) && (clip >= 0));
    }
    bool operator==(const canvasClip& a) const
    {//used in flood-fill to compare with target tile
        return ((tileset == a.tileset) && (clip == a.clip));
    }
    bool operator!=(const canvasClip& a) const
    {//used in flood-fill to compare with target tile
        return ((tileset != a.tileset) || (clip != a.clip));
    }
};
```

For this application, I expect to eventually want to generate maps with size upwards of 50000x50000 tiles, across indefinite (but probably never more than 10) layers. There are about 12 zones total, and that number is constant.

The map editor has some controls to change the size of the map (numeric inputs and a button). When I set the map size to a very large number, I call vector.resize() on each of those vectors, and I can watch my memory usage quickly travel upward in the task manager until my computer finally crashes.

Can anyone offer me some advice or tips for handling very large vectors? Am I going to have to do something like compress the vector so that a single index describes a span of similar tiles? Should I store the map in a file instead of memory, and then read-back only a few chunks of it at a time, as-needed?

How do good programmers handle this situation?

Comment: I'd hide the 3x3x3 vector in a class that has just a flat vector, and convert the 3x3x3 position (via the class's public API) into the internal flat vector.  If the data for the vector is actually too large to fit comfortably into memory, I'd make the class swap in/out to a backing store file.

Comment: Do you expect the user to work on multiple layers at once? I can think of a solution that involves storing all the layers in a file(s) except for the current layer and maybe two layers in either zoom direction. Now whenever the user proceeds to a new layer (zoom level), you can load one more in the zoom direction. If you maintain this balance, you should be able to have enough memory to manage all the tiles and you will only need a 2d vector rather than the insane 3d map you are currently managing. And you can do all this without harming the responsiveness

Comment: That `vector<vector<vector<canvasClip>>> CanvasClips`, assuming 10 layers, and 50000x50000 map, requires 50 GB for the data alone, assuming a 16-bit `int` - which will need to be stored in RAM.  For a 32-bit `int`, that requirement goes up to 100GB.   And that's not counting the overhead of the `std::vector`s themselves.    Good programmers will do that calculation, and find another way to represent their data - such as keeping only a part of the data in memory, and finding a way to read data as needed.

Comment: I'm kind of curious of the use case of a 50,000x50,000 tile map.  If each tile is 1 sq ft, the whole map would be almost 90 sq miles!  Assuming this is for a game, according to [this](https://www.thegamer.com/video-game-worlds-biggest-smallest/) list, your map would be the 16th largest map of all time!

Comment: @boxcartenant Could you try and only load the part of the map that is visible, and save the rest in a file loading it as you drew closer?

Comment: @0x5453 it's gonna be a pretty big world.  The goal is to support a large population of AI in 2d space, so that I can effectively stimulate a certain type of community I have in mind,  and eventually allow a population of players to share the map with them. I know memory management is going to become a big deal again when the AI come into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it already mentioned in the comments, you are trying to allocate huge amount of memory only for data.

In this case, you have to choose different data structure to store it and operate with it.

Here is a couple of the simplest tricks that you may apply in the cost of complexity of the code that operates the data:

1. You have default values that seem to be meaningless. Why not to store in memory only the data that is set to true values?
2. You may store in memory only visible part of data (see [Here's what's happening in Horizon: Zero Dawn every time you move a camera](https://www.reddit.com/r/horizon/comments/660jx6/heres_whats_happening_in_horizon_zero_dawn_every/)
   ).
3. You might have to pack your data structure and work on alignments (see [Data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)).

Of course, there is a case when you have to limit requirements, but that's a part of a life.